# z-index not working with modal popup extender

Tags: css, asp.net, modalpopupextender

There is a background image above which a div is placed. Now there is a modalpopup of Sign in which should appear at the top of div on click. But it is somehow appearing under the div. Expected result from bottom to top background image then div and then popup.
Here is what I am getting in image I provided:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCD9z.png
Expected result is popup should be at top

set z-index of div to 0 and 1. By default popup z-index is 10001 but still div is coming at top of it.

````
<style>
       body, html
       {
           height: 100%;
           margin: 0;
           font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       }

       *
       {
           box-sizing: border-box;
       }

       .bg-image
       {
           /* The image used */
           background-image: url(./Images/Stadium.jpg); /* Add the blur effect */ /*filter: blur(4px);
           -webkit-filter: blur(4px); /* Full height */
           height: 400px; /* Center and scale the image nicely */
           background-position: center;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-size: cover;
       }

       /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
       .bg-text
       {
           background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
           background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
           color: white;
           font-weight: bold;
           border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
           position: absolute;
           top: 40%;
           left: 50%;
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
           width: 60%;
           padding: 20px;
           text-align: center;
       }
   </style>

<div class="bg-image">
       </div>
       <div class="bg-text">
           <h2 style="font-variant: normal; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 1em; color: Black;
               margin: auto;">
               Find a Sports Coach</h2>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtSport" Style="margin-top: 100px;" runat="server" Font-Size="1em"
               Font-Bold="false" onblur="Javascript:FormatSport();"></asp:TextBox>
           <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 15px; text-align: left;"
               Text="Find" ValidationGroup="searchJob" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoc" runat="server" Font-Size="1em" Font-Bold="false" placeholder="Bangalore"
               ToolTip="Locations" onblur="Javascript:FormatLocation();"></asp:TextBox>
       </div>

<div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSignIn" runat="server" Text="Sign in" ForeColor="Black" Style="float: right;"></asp:LinkButton>
               <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp2" BehaviorID="behaviorIDmp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel2"
                   TargetControlID="lnkSignIn" CancelControlID="btnSignInCancel" DropShadow="true"
                   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
               </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
</div>
```[![Popup issue][1]][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCD9z.png
````

Comment: can u share the jsfiddle code

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with rendered html and css, but my guess is you need to look at your [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: I tried creating a html example but in that popup is apearing fine. Seems like it is the problem with modalpopup only. If modalpopup code is requred, do let me know

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body style="background-color: #F7F9F4; max-width: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div style="background-color: White; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 60px;">
        <br />
        <div style="float: left;" onclick="location.href='http://www.coachx.in'">
            <h1 style="font-family: @Comic Sans dMS, cursive, sans-serif; font-weight: 500; font-size: large;
                font-variant: normal; margin-left: 5px; letter-spacing: 1px; color: #043C61;
                text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
                CoachX</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline; margin: auto; text-align: center;">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkApplyToCoach" runat="server" PostBackUrl Text="Register As A Coach"
                    ForeColor="Black" Style="margin-left: 10px; float: right; margin-right: 10px;"></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSignIn" runat="server" Text="Sign in" ForeColor="Black" Style="margin-left: 10px;
                float: right; margin-right: 10px;"></asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp2" BehaviorID="behaviorIDmp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel2"
        TargetControlID="lnkSignIn" CancelControlID="btnSignInCancel" DropShadow="true"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none;
        height: 230px; width: 300px;" DefaultButton="btnSignIn">
        <h1 style="font-variant: normal; font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 1em; margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px; color: Gray;">
            Sign In</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSignInEmail" runat="server" class="txtFirstName" MaxLength="100"
            Width="200px" name="email" TabIndex="3" value="" placeholder="email address"
            Style="margin-top: 15px;" /><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblError" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false" Text="Incorrect Email\Password"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="true" ID="reqtxtSignInEmail" runat="server"
            ValidationGroup="modal" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtSignInEmail" ErrorMessage="Email Address Required"
            Display="Dynamic" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regtxtSignInEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Not Valid Email ID"
            ValidationGroup="modal" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSignInEmail"
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSignInPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="200px"
            placeholder="passowrd" class="txtFirstName" name="passwd" TabIndex="4" Style="margin-top: 15px;" /><br />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="true" ID="reqtxtSignInPassword" runat="server"
            ValidationGroup="modal" ControlToValidate="txtSignInPassword" ErrorMessage="Password Required"
            Display="Dynamic" Style="color: Red;" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSignIn" ValidationGroup="modal" class="btnempregsubmit" Width="100px"
            Height="25px" runat="server" Text="Log In" OnClick="btnSignIn_Click" CausesValidation="false"
            Style="clear: both;" />
        <br />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="btnSignInCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btnClosePopup">Close</asp:HyperLink>
    </asp:Panel>
    <div class="bg-image">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-text">
        <h1 style="font-variant: normal; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 2em; color: Black;
            margin: auto;">
            Find a Sports Coach</h1>
        <div style="margin-top: 30px;">
            <label style="float: left;">
                Search By Sport
            </label>
            <label style="float: right; margin-right: 120px;">
                Search By Location</label><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSport" Style="float: left; width: 220px; height: 30px; border-radius: 10px;
                background: White; padding: 15px;" runat="server" Font-Size="1.5em" Font-Bold="false"
                onblur="Javascript:FormatSport();"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLoc" runat="server" Style="float: right; width: 250px; height: 30px;
                border-radius: 10px; background: White; padding: 15px;" Font-Size="1.5em" Font-Bold="false"
                placeholder="Bangalore" ToolTip="Locations" onblur="Javascript:FormatLocation();"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" ValidationGroup="searchJob"
            OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Style="clear: both; margin-top: 30px; border-radius: 10px;
            height: 40px; background: Green; padding: 10px; width: 200px; font-size: large;" />
    </div>
```

The answer is the first top most div tag should finish just above the modalpopupextender. Earlier it was finishing at the end of code. Thanks all for your help.